# How do I resolve a formula error in Homebrew for imagemagick?

Tags: imagemagick, homebrew, rmagick

I'm running OS X and trying to get Homebrew, Ruby and Git to work together. I got everything installed and was trying to resolve gem errors.

I came across an issue with imagemagick and rmagick not working together, so I tried the solution described in "[Installing RMagick in Mac OS X Mountain Lion with Homebrew](http://blog.paulopoiati.com/2013/01/28/installing-rmagick-in-mac-os-x-mountain-lion-with-homebrew/)".

Now I am getting the following error when I try to do anything. How can I resolve this?

```
$ brew doctor
Error: /usr/local/Library/Formula/imagemagick.rb:99: syntax error, unexpected $end,    expecting kEND
Please report this bug:
    https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting
 /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:40:in `require'
 /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:40:in `klass'
 /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:90:in `get_formula'
 /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:175:in `factory'
 /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:404:in `factory'
 /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:340:in `each'
 /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:338:in `each'
 /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cmd/doctor.rb:814:in `check_for_linked_keg_only_brews'
 /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cmd/doctor.rb:1091:in `send'
 /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cmd/doctor.rb:1091:in `doctor'
 /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cmd/doctor.rb:1090:in `each'
 /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cmd/doctor.rb:1090:in `doctor'
 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb:95:in `send'
 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb:95
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was a syntax error in the formula. I fixed it and the solution worked.